# Access Violation Exception when using a C# Class Library To Write AVI File with a custom Directshow live source filter

Tags: c#, guid, access-violation, class-library, directshow.net

I'm trying to make a class library to write avi files. It uses Directshow.net library and build a filter graph behalf of the user. I also used `ComImport` to use a custom filter [from CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/158053/DirectShow-Filters-Development-Part-Live-Source). It is a live source filter and let user to feed the graph with bitmap samples at any time.

If I don't create a class library and use registered filter like the GSSF sample from Directshow.net library, everything work nice. I setup the graph and feed the graph with bitmaps. But when I want to wrap every directshow stuff into class and deliver a simple interface, I get an "AccessViolationException".

```
// C# TestApplication
using AVIReaderWriter;
AVIWriter aviWriter = new AVIWriter(...);
Bitmap tempBitmap = new Bitmap(....);
aviWriter.WriteFrame(tempBitmap);

// C# Library
using DirectshowLib;
public class AVIWriter{
    public AVIWriter(...){
        //Setup Directshow Graph
         capFilter = (IBaseFilter)new CLiveSource();
         liveSourceInterface = capFilter as ILiveSource;
    }
    public void WriteFrame(Bitmap bitmap){
        // iused LockBits and Marshal.copy to copy bitmap at pnt pointer.
        liveSourceInterface.AddFrame(pnt);
    }
}
//In Same project another file
[ComImport, Guid("63CA2EE3-6460-4098-9B74-079CE740E4B5")]
public class CLiveSource{}

[Guid("77F36C8D-DAB1-4356-8273-3FBE6063F257"),
InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface ILiveSource{
    [PreserveSig]
    int AddFrame([In] IntPtr hBmp);
    ....}
```

Comment: DirectShow was deprecated 11 years ago, replaced by Media Foundation.  High time it was, DS was getting quite fragile with far too many junk filters around.  The freeware "codec packs" were quite a scourge, I lost two months of my life on ffdshow.  Multiply that with DS.Net, times Codeproject.com, the "only works on my machine" site for code.  Time to cut your losses.